# Highlight trailing spaces in Neovim except for floating windows

Tags: neovim

I use NeoVim v0.4.2.

I want to highlight trailing spaces, so first I added the following to my vimrc:

```
augroup TrailingSpace
  au!
  au VimEnter,WinEnter * highlight link TrailingSpaces Error
  au VimEnter,WinEnter * match TrailingSpaces /\s\+$/
augroup END
```

But if then I open a floating window, such as an explorer by Defx, the window looks very awkward, like

```
file1---------------
file2            [T]
file3.txt-----------
```

(`-` represents that it is highlighted as `Error`.)

So I do not want to highlight trailing spaces in floating windows. I tried then the following instead:

```
augroup TrailingSpace
  au!
  au VimEnter,BufWinEnter * call HighlightTrailingSpaces()
augroup END

function! HighlightTrailingSpaces() abort
    if &filetype ==# 'defx'
        highlight clear TrailingSpaces
    else
        highlight link TrailingSpaces Error
    endif
    match TrailingSpaces /\s\+$/
endfunction
```

but this did not help me.

I have no idea at all how to highlight trailing spaces *without* highlighting in floating windows. Are there any useful functions (`autocmd` events?) for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you read through `:h BufWinEnter` it gets called as soon as a buffer is "displayed" in the window. At that point defx hasn't set the filetype which is why your intital if condition never gets triggered.

So, what you want to do instead is this:

```
augroup TrailingSpace
  au!
  au VimEnter,WinEnter * highlight link TrailingSpaces Error
  au VimEnter,WinEnter * match TrailingSpaces /\s\+$/
  au FileType defx highlight clear TrailingSpaces
augroup END
```

A slightly better option might be creating a file at `after/ftplugin/defx.vim` and adding `au FileType defx highlight clear TrailingSpaces` inside the file